# Grouping in Regex

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to do a match in regex.

It must match a string of characters of with the following formats:

Start with a C or H, w/ 6 characters following. (Total 7 characters long)
Start with KK and with 8 characters following. (Total 10 characters long)

The field is limited to 10 typed characters. I have the following:

`(((C|H).{6})|(KK.{8}))`

It matches KK+8 just fine. It fails on C+5 just fine. It succeeds on C+6 just fine. However it succeeds on C+7,C+8 and C+9.

I'm assuming my grouping is wrong, can anyone point out my error?

This is .NET flavored Regex and I'm using Regex.IsMatch to determine if the field exactly matches my regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string:

```
^([CH].{6}|KK.{8})$
```

I've also trimmed out the unnecessary parentheses and changed `(C|H)` to a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to improve readability.

Comment: Interesting, I was under the impression IsMatch ensured the entire string matched, I guess I was mistaken. Thanks!

Comment: @Aequitarum Custos: You might have been thinking of the similarly named method `matches` from Java which requires an exact match.

Comment: Aha yes you're right, .NET has the same thing. Not used to validating input strings, used to parsing. Explains my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You you want to capture anything from the pattern?
If not, I would try this one:

```
^(KK..|C|H).{6}$
```

Comment: +1 for being functional and simpler. I believe the above is the correct way for my approach though as these string formats are state specified and either could change independently of the other.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the start and end of line [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
^(((C|H).{6})|(KK.{8}))$
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Mark Byers answer best, with this modification (tested for .NET):

```
^[CH].{6}$|^KK.{8}$
```

The original will give a false match for values with more than 6 characters after a C or H.